# Vim: How do you highlight a search pattern from script?

Tags: vim, vimscript

I would not have thought that this would be hard to do, but it's not working.  What I'm trying to do is enable the search highlight from script.  I've tried the following:

```
function! g:TestFunc()
    let @/ ="testtext"
    set hlsearch
endfunction

nnoremap <space> :call g:TestFunc()<cr>
```

Which doesn't work.  That is, hitting space in front of some text with "testtext" in it does not highlight the text.  The user still has to hit 'n'.

I also tried adding `exec 'normal! n'` to the end of the function but that also didn't work.  Even `feedkeys('n')` fails.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The function works as expected if `hlsearch` is unset before calling it. It appears that setting it in the function has no effect if it's already set. You can work around this by setting `nohlsearch` in your mapping:

```
nnoremap <space> :set nohlsearch\|:call g:TestFunc()<cr>
```

If your goal is simply to highlight certain patterns, and you don't specifically need to use the `hlsearch` mechanism, you may want to look into using the `match` command instead. It accomplishes much the same thing more cleanly.

Comment: that match command is exactly what I was looking for, cheers!

Answer (score 1):

You cannot set the last used search pattern and highlighting from within a function, see `:help function-search-undo`. Instead, move the `:set hlsearch` directly into your mapping.

Answer (score 0):

```
function! wordsubstitute#run()
    execute "normal! gv\"ay"
    let @/ = @a
    "set nohlsearch
    let s:search_cmd = "normal! /".@/."/\<CR>"
    execute s:search_cmd."N"
    "set hlsearch
endfunction
```

Instead of using `normal! nN`, write `nN` in the mapping command:

```
vnoremap [g/ :<c-u>call wordsubstitute#run()<CR>nN
```